# Java program not liking the word "Scanner"

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    Scanner infile = new Scanner(new FileReader("historyGrades.txt"));
    boolean[] correctAnswers = new boolean[20];
    infile.close();
  }
}
```

I'm getting these errors for some reason:

```
C:\Users\Rawr\Documents\Test.java:11: cannot resolve symbol
symbol  : class Scanner 
location: class Test
    Scanner infile = new Scanner(new FileReader("historyGrades.txt"));
    ^
C:\Users\Rawr\Documents\Test.java:11: cannot resolve symbol
symbol  : class Scanner 
location: class Test
    Scanner infile = new Scanner(new FileReader("historyGrades.txt"));
                         ^
2 errors

Tool completed with exit code 1
```

I have no idea what's going on. 
Help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you `import java.util.Scanner;` explicitly?

Comment: this: http://pastebin.com/SxQi7NDK

Comment: It's likely your compiler compliance level. You're likely compiling at 1.4, not 1.5 or 1.6 as we've noted below.

Comment: As an aside, you should never need to `import java.lang.*`. It's implied. (That's where `Object` and `String` come from, among other things...)

Comment: You are using a version which is lower than 1.5. Or, you are compiling with a version lower than 1.5.

Comment: execute javac -version and see what is the version because sometime though you have installed the latest version, someone may has alrady configured to some other version.

Answer (score 3):

Which version of Java are you using? `Scanner` was added in 1.5.

Comment: not sure, Just whatever came with my Book CD is what Im using. Everything has worked fine up to now.

Comment: Are you using javac to compile, or an IDE (like Eclipse)? If javac, you can run `javac -version` to find the version.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command on command prompt (terminal);

```
java -version
```

If the returned version number is less than 1.5 then you have to download the new version of Java. Scanner class is not available in prior versions. Download the new version of SDK from here;

[Java SE Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk6-jsp-136632.html)

After setting up the new version of Java, add the following import statement in your source file;

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Now compile your source. It should go like a F16 now. But feel free to ask in case of any problem.